# AS/400 error message - Cannot allocate device

Tags: ibm-midrange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AS/400 error message - Cannot allocate device](https://serverfault.com/questions/221689/as-400-error-message-cannot-allocate-device)

whn i process any action like to initialize a tape device... or display tape... i get error msg "cannot allocate device (tap01)" in the command window.. plz help... am new to AS/400... i want to initialzie a fresh tap to take backup... on daily process... but am gettin this error msg :(

Comment: This should be moved to ServerFault.

Comment: Add a detailed (F10'd) copy/paste of the joblog for the command in question.  Also, pressing F1 with the cursor on the error message itself will give you more details.  And include the error code (CPFxxxx).

Answer (score 1):

Without sufficient detail in the question, I suggest you do a WRKOBJLCK on the object (e.g. TAP01 *DEV) to see if something else has a lock on it which is preventing you from accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would look at is to make sure the device is varied on. `WRKDEVD DEVD(TAP*)` Then option `8` next to the device.